# Add application blog to my Django project

Tags: python, django

`Django = 2.0`
I want this app to add to my project - https://github.com/pythonsd/test-driven-django-development/tree/master/myblog

It works for me, but I don't need comments.
And I can't figure out how to delete these comments. In HTML I know how to remove it, but I want to remove comments from models and views, I want to have clean code in my project.

https://github.com/pythonsd/test-driven-django-development/blob/master/myblog/blog/models.py - I am to delete class `Comment(models.Model)` , right?  I think yes.

https://github.com/pythonsd/test-driven-django-development/blob/master/myblog/blog/views.py - But what I need to remove from the file, if I do not have the comments in my `blog-app`?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class EntryDetail(DetailView):
    model = Entry
    template_name = 'test/blog-detail.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.get_object().get_absolute_url()
```

it is work.